# How to visualise Inheritance and Polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop

I want to make diagrams that explain how Inheritance and Polymorphism work conceptually.

Assume that we have a `Cat` class that inherits from the `Animal` class. The way that I can think of a `Cat` object is that it is an object that contains a copy of the members of the `Cat` class and also it have an `Animal` object inside of it.

*Note: technically, I think that all `Cat` objects share the same copy of the methods of the `Cat` class, however, it is clearer to conceptually think of every `Cat` object as if it contains its own copy of the methods of the `Cat` class.*

Now when we do:

```
Cat cat1 = new Cat();
```

Then `cat1` will point to the `Cat` object, this is how the diagram would look like:

[image]

The operations that are allowed on the `cat1` variable are the following:

- `cat1.x` (will access the `x` variable inside the `Cat` object).
- `cat1.move()` (will call the `move()` method inside the `Cat` object).
- `cat1.jump()` (will call the `jump()` method inside the `Animal` object).

And when we do:

```
Animal animal1 = cat1;
```

Then `animal1` will point to the `Animal` object that is inside the `Cat` object, this is how the diagram would look like:

[image]

*Note: the arrow pointing at the `Animal` object doesn't mean that `animal1` actually point to a different location in memory than `cat1`, the truth is that `animal1` and `cat1` point to the same location in memory, the arrow pointing at the `Animal` object is just to indicate that `animal1` can only access the members inside the `Animal` object (unless we have an overridden method).*

The operations that are allowed on the `animal1` variable are the following:

- `animal1.x` (will access the `x` variable inside the `Animal` object).
- `animal1.move()` (now if the `move()` method is not overridden in the `Cat` class, then `animal1.move()` should call the `move()` method inside the `Animal` object, however, since the `move()` method is overridden in the `Cat` class, then `animal1.move()` would call the `move()` method inside the `Cat` object).
- `animal1.jump()` (will call the `jump()` method inside the `Animal` object).

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You may want to look at UML notation. Specifically class diagram and object diagram.

Comment: I don't particularly like the latter diagram - the animal1 reference points to an internal Animal object, but I can't "take it out" of the enclosing object, nor can I call the Animal::move() method like I could if that inner object wasn't "inside" a cat. I think sticking to visualizing with vtables, like [here](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2017/06/10/understanding-virtual-tables/#so-how-do-we-implement-dynamic-dispatch), is both easier and has a benefit of being closer to the real implementation.

Comment: (or, to simplify things - each object internally carries a list of method implementations, which is how it knows to call Cat::move() even if you call move() via an Animal reference. In practice this is a pointer to a list of pointers to functions, but that's an implementation detail)